# Writing to different sources in Apache Beam

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a simeple pipeline whihc write from s3 to pubsub as follow

```
   Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);

    /*
     * Steps:
     *  1) Read from the text source.
     *  2) Write each text record to Pub/Sub
     */
    pipeline
        .apply("Read Text Data", TextIO.read().from(options.getInputFilePattern()))
        .apply("Write to PubSub", PubsubIO.writeStrings().to(options.getOutputTopic()));


    State p= pipeline.run().waitUntilFinish();
```

However, I want to concurrently write the records to another s3 bucket. How to change above codes to write to another bucket as well?

Answer (score 3):

I expect your question is about how to handle the input so that it can be output to two sources. Below idea should work:

```
PCollection<String> inputCollection= pipeline.apply("Read Text Data", TextIO.read().from(options.getInputFilePattern()));
inputCollection.apply("Write to PubSub",PubsubIO.writeStrings().to(options.getOutputTopic()));
inputCollection.apply("Write to S3 Bucket",<appropriate-IO>.to(options.getOutputPath()));
State p= pipeline.run().waitUntilFinish();
```

Comment: He can use TextIO.write(), more information on  [https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.0.0/index.html?org/apache/beam/sdk/io/TextIO.Write.html]